# Testing assert.Equal except one field

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm writing a test for reading/writing a struct in a DB and one of its fields is a timestamp which is auto-calculated in the DB. So when I write the struct its timestamp is 0 but when I read it from the DB the timestamp has an actual value.

I want to compare the two values but to ignore the auto-calculated field. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Set the other "except" field prior to testing:

```
now := time.Now()
expected := SomeStruct{
    ID:       123,
    Name:     "Test",
    Timestamp: now,
    ...
}
result, _ := db.Select(....)
result.Timeestamp = now
if !reflect.DeepEqual(result, expected) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is just a workaround hack. I want to say somehow that it's totally legit for one field to be different.

Comment: If you want to literally compare everything except that field, you'll need to do it manually, field-by-field.  The effect is identical, though, so I consider this neither a "work-around" nor a "hack".

Comment: How would this work if the other "except" field is a non-exported field defined in another module?

Comment: @KurtPeek: The `github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp` is probably your best bet in that case. In fact, I'd use it in all cases where deep equality is desired now. I didn't know about that package in 2017 (if it even existed at the time).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using `IgnoreFields` function of the [cmpopts package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts#IgnoreFields).

Here's an example:

```
got, want := FuncUnderTest()

if !cmp.Equal(want, got, cmpopts.IgnoreFields(YourStruct{}, "FieldName")) {
    t.Errorf("FuncUnderTest() mismatch")
}
```